# Сервис на symfony

Tags: symfony3

Решил сделать сервис для упрощения работы.
services.yml:

```
crud:
    class: AppBundle\Service\CRUD
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@service_container"]
    public: true
```

CRUD.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;

class CRUD
{
    protected $em;
    private $container;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Container $container)
    {
        $this->em           =   $entityManager;
        $this->container    =   $container;
    }
}
```

Вызываю в контроллере:

```
$crud = $this->get('crud');
    var_dump($crud);
    exit;
```

В итоге страница постоянно грузиться...в чем может быть дело?

Comment: В `$crud` очень много данных. Попробуйте заменить `var_dump($crud);` на `echo get_class($crud);`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! А `$crud` не будет влиять на скорость работы всего остального кода или это так виснет из-за `var_dump($crud);`?

Comment: Это из-за `var_dump`. Оно пытается вывести гигантское дерево свойств объекта `$crud` в браузер, и  браузер виснет. Это не влияет на производительность.

Comment: вам уже помогли, но если хотите работать с symfony правильно, то никогда не передавайте контейнер в сервисы

Answer (score 0):

У вас долго грузится, потом что объект объемный.
В симфони есть удобная функция для вывода больших объектов, в т.ч. прокси-объектов доктрины:

```
dump($crud);
```